# Custom Controls: How to make each instance of, not shared?

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, textbox, custom-controls

This one is a little hard to explain.
I have created a custom control of textbox. I made 20 my.settings 'specialized string collections'. I have made a property dropdown box to select which my.settings the user wishes to use on that instance of the textbox. The textbox is supposed to insert every entry into the selected my.settings collection to auto suggest it later in it's 'autocompletecustomsource' feature. I want each instance to have it's own separate collection. However, when populating it's 'autocompletecustomsource' with the strings in the collection, every instance gets the same strings. I thought that maybe every instance of a textbox shared the same autocomplete but I tried doing this manually with 2 regular textboxes and that actually worked. So now I think that

> me.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(item)

the "me" refers to every instance.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Enum Books
    Collection_1
    Collection_2
    Collection_3
    Collection_4
    Collection_5
    Collection_6
    Collection_7
    Collection_8
    Collection_9
    Collection_10
    Collection_11
    Collection_12
    Collection_13
    Collection_14
    Collection_15
    Collection_16
    Collection_17
    Collection_18
    Collection_19
    Collection_20
End Enum

'<Serializable()>
Public Class AutoSavingTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Dim Save As Boolean = True
    Private myBook As Books
    Dim savedList As Object


    Public Sub New()
        If books = Books.Collection_1 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection1
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_2 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection2
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_3 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection3
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_4 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection4
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_5 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection5
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_6 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection6
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_7 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection7
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_8 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection8
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_9 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection9
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_10 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection10
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_11 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection11
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_12 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection12
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_13 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection13
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_14 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection14
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_15 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection15
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_16 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection16
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_17 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection17
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_18 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection18
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_19 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection19
        ElseIf books = Books.Collection_20 Then
            savedList = My.Settings.ASTBcollection20
        End If

        With Me
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        End With

        For Each item In savedList
            Me.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(item)
        Next
End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToSettings()
        savedList.Add(Me.Text)
        My.Settings.Save()
        For Each item In savedList
            Me.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub AutoSavingTextBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If Save = True Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                SaveToSettings()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    <Category("Auto-Saving TextBox")>
    <DisplayName("Saving on Enter")>
    <Description("When set to true, hitting the Enter key in the textbox will save the entry to this control's AutoCompleteSource.")>
    Public Property Saving() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Save
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Save = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Auto-Saving TextBox")>
    <DisplayName("Book")>
    <Description("Choose which collection to use.")>
    Public Property books() As Books
        Get
            Return myBook
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Books)
            myBook = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: First, I don't see how this could compile. If you are using Visual Studio don't you notice a few read squiggles? You need to attend to these before compiling. `savedList.Add(Me.Text)` `savedList` is declared as an `Object`. `Object` doesn't have an `.Add` method. Also `For Each item In savedList` `Object` is not a collection type.

Comment: i was trying to declare my.settings as a variable. how do i do that then?
edit: i dont see any squiggles at all in my project. 0 errors. 0 warnings, and only 1 message saying that Books should be captialized.

Comment: `Dim savedList As New StringCollection()` got rid of the errors. I pasted your code to Visual Studio 2019 Community and got the errors.

Comment: You may need to consider the following "Scope indicates if the property is read-only. If the value is Application, the property is read-only; if the value is User, the property is read-write." This is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object